# Android slow file download

Tags: android, file-io, httpclient

I am downloading on my android app. I am using a local network connection and the download is really slow.

Here's he code I am using:

```
URL url = new URL(ep.getFileURL());
File destFile = new File(<path to sd card file>);

URLConnection uCon = url.openConnection();
InputStream is = uCon.getInputStream();
OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(destFile);

int progress = 0;
int lastProgress = 0;
int totalSize = uCon.getContentLength();
int downloadedSize = 0;
byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
int count = -1;
while((count = is.read(buffer)) != -1)
{
    os.write(buffer, 0, count);

downloadedSize = downloadedSize + count;
    progress = (int)(downloadedSize * 100.0 / totalSize);
    if(progress - lastProgress >= 5) {
        publishProgress(progress);
        lastProgress = progress;
    }
}

os.close();
```

Do you spot any problems? thank you.

**Edit:**

I tested my code using your suggestions and I got these results:

```
# Download times tests #

Without bufferedoutput
Downloading file:      1 ms, Start download
Downloading file:      179812 ms, Finished downloading 54687744 bytes
Downloading file: end, 179813 ms

With bufferedoutput
Downloading file:      1 ms, Start download
Downloading file:      178312 ms, Finished downloading 54687744 bytes
Downloading file: end, 178313 ms

With httpclient
Downloading file: begin
Downloading file:      1 ms, Start download
Downloading file:      178241 ms, Finished downloading 54687744 bytes
Downloading file: end, 178242 ms
```

So, using Buffered streams or using HttpClient directly, doesn't change anything...

I also should have mentioned that my code is inside a AsyncTask, so publishProgress() actually runs on a separated thread already...

Thank you for your help.

Comment: What speed are you getting, and what speed to you expect to get? If you're questioning the speed of your IO, the first thing you should do is time it, so that you can tell if your improvements make a significant difference.

Comment: what do you do in publishProgress()? (a little code would be helpful..)

Answer (score 5):

You should wrap your input stream with a BufferedInputStream.  You're probably getting a lot more shallow reads of a few bytes and a buffered stream will alleviate some of that.  I would try that first, buffering both the input and output streams to reduce the OS level write delays.

Second, I'd be careful with how you are posting progress.  It looks like you are limiting the number of times it comes up, but you might want to move the download into its own runnable and use an executor service for the download and maybe start an additional thread which evaluates the progress of all downloads and fires progress messages as necessary.

Comment: The FileOutputStream should probably be wrapped in a BufferedOutputStream too. I'm guessing that this is part of an AsyncTask in Android, so publishProgress will queue a message on the UI thread, without blocking the download. So publishProgress is *probably* not an issue here.

Answer (score 3):

Use `HttpClient` instead of `URLConnection`